# What is the fastest method to get "const wchar_t*" from QString

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, wchar-t

I want to pass a `QString` variable to a function with `const wchar_t*` argument.

Safe solution is:

```
void foo(const wchar_t*);
QString x = "test";
foo(x.toStdWString().c_str());
```

but it has overhead of converting to `wstring`. Is there any faster solution?

How about this solution? Is it safe and portable?

```
foo(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(x.constData()));
```

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is practically the definition of potentially unsafe and unportable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [QChar to wchar\_t](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726805/qchar-to-wchar-t)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the reinterpret cast is not safe and will not work on some platforms where the encoding is different. `QChar` is 16-bit and the internal encoding is UTF-16, but on Linux `wchar_t` is 32-bit UCS-4 encoding.

The cast would happen to work (it's still undefined behaviour, but msc++ does not currently do anything that would break it) on Windows where `wchar_t` is forever stuck at 16 bit, but the point of using Qt is being portable, right?

Note, that the conversion via `std::wstring` is as efficient as you can get. Given the difference in encoding memory has to be allocated once, which is managed by the `std::wstring` (the return copy can be elided even in C++98) and `std::wstring::c_str()` is a trivial getter.

Comment: The cast is **always** wrong.  Either `wchar_t` is identical to `unsigned short`, and no cast is needed, or else they are separate types, and the cast invokes illegal aliasing (strict aliasing violation aka type punning).

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes. But msc++ does not optimize based on strict aliasing and I even recall Microsoft saying somewhere they don't plan it, because they are aware how much code that violates it exists in the wild (and probably have good chunk of it themselves). I reworded the paragraph a bit.

Comment: The most efficient way is `toWCharArray` which can avoid dynamic memory allocation and does not need to construct (and destruct) an `std::wstring` instance.

Answer (score -1):

If `x.constData` gives you data addressable as `const wchar_t*`, you won't need a cast.

Any situation which won't compile without a cast, is badly broken (illegal aliasing and most likely also incompatible encoding).

It looks like the correct way is `x.utf16()` (no cast), and even then only when `wchar_t` is `unsigned short`.  See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#utf16

`QString` is always UTF-16, so if `wchar_t` isn't, then there is no method without conversion.

Comment: No! it gives QChar*. and QChar typedefed to unsigned short.

Comment: @A.Danesh: `QChar` looks like a class, not a `typedef`.  Anyway, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/7360480/103167

Comment: -1 after the edit. The whole point is that `QString` is UTF-16, but `wchat_t` is **NOT!** The intention of the specification is clearly that `wchar_t` is constant-width encoding, which for Unicode 3 and newer takes 4 bytes (3, but 3-byte types are inpractical) and some systems follow that. The fact that Windows API is now stuck with 16-bit `wchar_t` due to baking it into system calls notwithstanding.

Comment: Also, `QString::utf16()` **does** need a cast to `const wchar_t *`, because `wchar_t` is a distinct type not equal to `unsigned short` (required by C++ specification) unless you are compiling with MSVC++ and set the bug-compatibility option `/Zc:wchar_t-`.

Comment: @Jan: Your comments seem to agree with my answer.  Edited a bit for clarity.  But the `QString` content can be used directly only on systems where `wchar_t` is `unsigned short`.  Otherwise you need a conversion.  Not a cast.

Comment: @BenVoigt: And there are _no_ systems where `wchar_t` is `unsigned short`, because C++ standard requires that it isn't. MSVC++ has a backward compatibility option, `/Zc:wchar_t-`, that makes `wchar_t` a typedef for `unsigned char`, but it only exists to simplify compiling ancient code, is not selected by default and is not compatible with most libraries you'll get.

Comment: Note, that C differs. In C, `wchar_t` can be alias for some integral type. But in C++ it is a distinct primitive type. But Qt is C++, so what C does is not relevant. `g++` and `clang++` always treat `wchar_t` as distinct type and I have not seen non-windows platform using any other compiler for quite long.